# counter is increment the value when click on add field but not decrements when click on remove field

Tags: javascript, jquery

On clicking add field button the text field on the top shows increment which is correct but when I click on the remove field button the value is showing increment instead of decrements.

```
<div id="awaien">
    <input type="text" value="1" name="cntr" />
</div>
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email</label>
        <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
        <p>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Email" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($team->email);?>" />
        </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var scntDiv = $('input_fields_wrap');
    var i = $('#input_fields_wrap p').size() + 1;

    var max_fields = 20; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="Email' + i +'"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
        i++;
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
        i--;
        x--;
    })
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".input_fields_wrap").on('click',function(){
        $("#awaien input").val(parseInt($("#awaien input").val()) + 1);
    });
    $(".remove_field").on('click',function(){
        $("#awaien input").val(parseInt($("#awaien input").val()) - 1);
    });
});
```

How can we resolve the issue so that when i click on the remove field button it should decrements?

Answer (score 0):

You have some mistakes in your code and some logic very strange, however i have tried to make it correct maximum that i can:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var scntDiv = $('input_fields_wrap');
    var i = $('#input_fields_wrap p').size() + 1;

    var max_fields = 20; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="Email' + i +'"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
            i++;
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
        $("#awaien input").val(parseInt($("#awaien input").val()) - 1);
        i--;
        x--;
    });
    $(".add_field_button").on('click',function(){
        $("#awaien input").val(parseInt($("#awaien input").val()) + 1);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="awaien">
    <input type="text" value="1" name="cntr" />
</div>
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email</label>
        <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
        <p>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Email" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($team->email);?>" />
        </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are executing this part

```
$(".remove_field").on('click',function(){
    $("#awaien input").val(parseInt($("#awaien input").val()) - 1);
});
```

out side of document ready. Meaning that the button doesn't exist yet and thus no handles will be attached. change

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".input_fields_wrap").on('click',function(){
    $("#awaien input").val(parseInt($("#awaien input").val()) + 1);
});
$(".remove_field").on('click',function(){
    $("#awaien input").val(parseInt($("#awaien input").val()) - 1);
});
```

to

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".input_fields_wrap").on('click',function(){
    $("#awaien input").val(parseInt($("#awaien input").val()) + 1);

    $(".remove_field").on('click',function(){
        $("#awaien input").val(parseInt($("#awaien input").val()) - 1);
    });
});
```